# Access general settings trough wordpress files

Tags: options, https, http

I was reading an article about HTTPS and that you could turn on SSL and HTTPS for Wordpress quite easily.

However in the article it said that you should go to Settings > General Settings within the admin panel and change Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) from http:// to https://.

However after doing this I'm no longer able to access my admin panel as it always wants to go to https. I just get to a page that says "This webpage is not available"

So my question is, would it be possible for my to navigate trough the Wordpress Install files and undo this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to amend those items from the database.

In the table `wp_options` there are the option_names `home` and `siteurl` - editing these back to the `http` version should do the trick.

You might also want to check your `wp-config.php` file for the following:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.website.com/');                   
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.website.com/');
```

And remove the 's' here as well.

Turning on HTTPS and SSL for WordPress is very easy and what you have done will work - so long as you have already uploaded and installed a valid SSL certificate onto your server, without this there is no way for the server to actually be certified, and the https website url will not work.